# How to access "required" value in view file using Kohana Formo

Tags: kohana

I have a following code initializing Formo

```
$form = Formo::form();

$form->add('field', 'input', 'default', array('required'=>true));
```

How do I access the "required" value inside the view file?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Form Docs](https://github.com/bmidget/kohana-formo/blob/3.2/master/guide/formo/formo.html_kind.md):

```
$required = $field->view()->attr('required');
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the docs, after playing around, the solution for me is `$required = $this->_field->get('required');` . However, the examples in the docs, `$form` and `$field` is **not available** in the view file.